# Did Hitler ever tell a joke?

Tags: hitler

Did Hitler ever tell a joke, and was it funny? Was it recorded on video or audio? 3-4 different people commented on a comic claiming the artist is a Neo-Nazi. I don't see what that has to do with anything because the comic itself had nothing to do with Nazism and was funny. However it made me wonder if 'literally Hitler' ever expressed a sense of humor and did people find it funny?

I found this question: [What was Hitler like in private?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/15489/what-was-hitler-like-in-private) but it didn't mention jokes or humor or comedy. The referenced Wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitler%27s_Table_Talk also did not mention them.

According to the movie Downfall, he seemed rather serious.

Comment: At 5:40 [here](https://www.dailymotion.com/video/x2hwqqd) and a different one at 9:00

Comment: "was it funny" is not going to be objectively answerable.

Comment: Can't post an answer so here you go: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtDxjVCu56E

Comment: Which does human has never told a joke? A more fitting title would be "Are there recorded jokes told by Hitler?"

Comment: Humor is all about context, and in context nothing about the man is really funny.

Comment: I think a more apt comparison to a comic is "Has Hitler ever done something that was widely thought of as good?", and I remember hearing that he had a program to plant flowers in front of factories, before all the genocide and war stuff.

Comment: @AaronBrick Sure it is. You can replay the joke to an audience and measure the percentage which laughs. This can be done as a controlled experiment if you really want to.

Comment: It's been a while since I saw Downfall, but if I recall the movie correctly, as der Führer, Hitler was a very serious man. But sweet uncle Adolf was quite fun.

Comment: Obviously he has - and you would have done well to laugh at it were it told to you.

Comment: Do you mean funny... in retrospect?

Comment: You, and all of the answerers, seem to forget that Adolf Hitler had a life before 1933 when he became Chancellor, and a life before the Putsch in 1923.  Are you confining this question to when he was Chancellor, or his whole life?  Like Goering, he served in WW I.   Unlike Goering, he was in the infantry.  I find it unlikely that, being a solider in the Kaiser's Army who served during a war, he didn't learn a few and tell a few jokes.  So, what's the time frame that you are asking about?

Comment: @T.E.D.  *nothing about the man is really funny* - I am under the impression that his art professors found his compositions laughable.

Comment: Although it is not directly germane to the OP, the Nazi regime had an official humor publication. It was named _Der Brennessel_ (The Nettle), relied mostly on satire, and by the accounts I have read its attempts at humor rarely if ever succeeded.

Comment: @JBentley what audience? What day? What place? How was it set up? There are to many variables to realistically account for to accurately measure the "degree of funniness" (with what unit? lols?). Under the right circumstances anything can be considered funny by at least one individual.

Comment: @DanM. Variables don't prevent objective analysis. For example how do you measure the success of a cancer treatment? What country are the participants from, what income level, what was their diet, did they smoke, how do you measure whether it worked (how much tumour shrinkage, how many years before it returns, etc.). Under the right circumstances [a treatment can work on at least one individual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Patient) too. None of these things prevent us from being objective about them.

Comment: @JBentley sometimes they do though. To answer the question "was it funny" (in the absence of the any historical evidence) you need to reproduce 100% exact circumstances the joke was told, including both the context and the audience, which is harder than proving that russell's teapot doesn't exist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to [Rochus Misch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rochus_Misch), the Berlin Bunker telephonist and part of the [Führerbegleitkommando](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SS-Begleitkommando_des_F%C3%BChrers) (Führer Escort Command; FBK), Hitler did tell jokes but

> I cannot state for a fact that Hitler had a sense of humour. I never
>   heard him laugh out loud. That may be because I did not know him until
>   after the war began. The Old Campaigners [those who had been with Hitler before he came to power] told me that the warlord
>   Hitler was a quite different personality to the pre-war Hitler. ‘The
>   boss’ himself had a small fund of jokes, which he liked to bring out
>   from time to time.

*Source: Rochus Misch, '[Hitler's Last Witness](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Hitler_s_Last_Witness.html?id=TuqwBAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)' (2014, but originally published in German in 2008)*

Misch does not detail these jokes other than a rather unimaginative sexist joke relating to his dog [Blondi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blondi). Not being part of the inner circle, Misch may not have heard Hitler laugh much but other sources say that he did (see [here](https://archive.org/details/hitlerbooksecret00parp/page/160/mode/2up) and [here](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=HcBsDwAAQBAJ&q=profax#v=snippet&q=laugh&f=false)). A [Daily Telegraph article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/germany/2185507/Adolf-Hitler-told-bad-jokes-about-Nazi-friends.html) of the book cites this Hitler joke:

> he noticed his official photographer [Heinrich Hoffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Hoffmann_(photographer)) had drunk too
>   much and told him: "Don't stand to near the fire Heini - you might
>   burst into flames."

It further mentions the Goering joke cited by *Chloe*. The article also mentions that, with reference to Goering's penchant for awarding himself medals,

> Hitler was said to be so proud of his joke that he had medals made
>   from gold and silver paper for Goering to wear on his pyjamas.

However, neither of the Goering jokes cited by *The Daily Telegraph* come from Misch (as is clear from this Daily Mail article on the same book). The medal joke, though, is mentioned (with a minor variation) in *[The Hitler Book](https://archive.org/details/hitlerbooksecret00parp/page/68/mode/2up)*, prepared by the [NKVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NKVD) for Stalin (so a source that needs treated with some caution), and it is not the only Goering medal joke (see below).

Hitler had a tendency to make fun of and mock others, including their deaths (General [Hellmuth Stieff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellmuth_Stieff), [for example](https://archive.org/details/hitlerbooksecret00parp/page/160/mode/2up), who was executed for his part in the [20 July plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_July_plot) to kill Hitler). He also made fun of Admiral [Erich Raeder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erich_Raeder)'s “sanctimonious Christianity” and apparently of [André François-Poncet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Fran%C3%A7ois-Poncet), the French ambassador to Germany:

> Because of his repeated favorable statements, François-Poncet
>   mockingly was called the “Reich Speaker of the NSDAP” in Germany prior
>   to 1938. Even Hitler once offered him this title as a joke

*Source: Max Domarus, '[The Complete Hitler - Speeches and Proclamations](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/THE_COMPLETE_HITLER_Speeches_and_Proclam.html?id=KJm8BgAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y)'*

Going back to Goering's medals, [Friedelind Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedelind_Wagner), daughter of [Siegfried Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegfried_Wagner) and granddaughter of the Nazis' favourite composer [Richard Wagner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Wagner) provides another example of Hitler's humor at the expense of others. In the presence of Goering and Goebbels, Hitler said to the Wagner family:

> You all know what a volt is an ampere, don’t you? Right. But do you
>   know what a goebbels, a goering are? A goebbels is the amount of
>   nonsense a man can speak in an hour and a goering is the amount of
>   metal that can be pinned on a man’s breast.

*Source: Walter C. Langer, '[A psychological Analysis of Adolph Hitler](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP78-02646R000600240001-5.pdf)' (Office of Strategic Services)*

According to Langer, when in the mood, Hitler enjoyed "a kind of teasing and ribbing":

> He is an excellent mimic and often plays out the role of the
>   individual involved to the great amusement of the staff while the
>   individual must sit by and witness the performance much to his own
>   embarrassment.

Among the people he liked to mimic (but who were unlikely to have had to sit through the performance) were the British Ambassador to Germany (1933-37) [Eric Phipps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Phipps) and the British Prime Minister (1937-40) [Neville Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville_Chamberlain).

Race was (inevitably) another area which Hitler saw fit to joke about. According to *The Hitler Book*, Hitler made a joke about the 'racial purity' of the Vichy politician [Pierre Laval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Laval).

Hitler's favourite photographer Heinrich Hoffmann, in his memoir [Hitler Was My Friend](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=HcBsDwAAQBAJ&q=profax#v=snippet&q=profax&f=false), also relates a number of Hitler jokes, none of which are worth repeating.

Whether Hitler's jokes were funny or not is not (as *Aaron Brick* observed in a comment) "objectively answerable". At best, many seem simply lame and are more quips than jokes. At worst, well, let's not go there.

---

Concerning the Franco joke mentioned in Quora and cited by *Chloe*, this [appears to be cited](https://www.economist.com/books-and-arts/2013/08/10/rebels-with-a-cause) in *[Franco’s Crypt: Spanish Culture and Memory Since 1936](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0374108420)* by Jeremy Treglown. It is also mentioned in Philip Thody's book *[Jean-Paul Sartre](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=vEhdDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA68&lpg=PA68&dq=%22hitler%22%20%22franco%22%20%22dentist%22%20joke&source=bl&ots=mznpAWHhq7&sig=ACfU3U2L_4G7_mqzWkpGrhXuim_zG6S7BA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjS0O-Pu77nAhUYOisKHdvFC28Q6AEwC3oECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22hitler%22%20%22franco%22%20%22dentist%22%20joke&f=false)*, but with no footnote as to the original source.

---

*Other source*:

*Henry D. Murray, '[Analysis of the Personality of Adolph Hitler](https://www.cia.gov/library/readingroom/docs/CIA-RDP78-02646R000100030002-2.pdf)' (Records of the Central Intelligence Agency)*

Comment: Those jokes just make him sound like an asshole.

Comment: @Parrotmaster, there are a couple of other details leading to that judgement as well.

Comment: For that Göring-Underpants joke I'd like to see the German original. I suspect that this is *not* a directly translated quip AH told – at all. It seems to not work well in that language (& is of course nowhere in Misch's book)? Is that yet another unreliable, invented quote surrounding AH?

Comment: The pajama medal joke is funny.

Comment: If it wasn't bad enough for him to be a genocidal maniac, Hitler was also an asshole. @parrotmaster

Comment: @Parrotmaster ...who would have imagined that the Fuhrer was an asshole...

Comment: This quotes Misch selectively, neglects the apparent contradiction in *1* book, is still too weak on Misch *surely* not being the 'source' of this 'joke', is too approving of Telegraph as src for two wrongly attributed jokes. If you want the Franco bit: copypastaed by *a lot* published historians (to a wrong src) too: Ciano's Diplomatic Papers, p402 but tellingly, *not* in his diaries!). Remember that post-war, everyone was resistance.

Comment: @LаngLаngС Still working on it, but please note that I have stated there is no footnote for the original source for the Franco bit.

Comment: Noted, indeed. Am *much* less angry at this A (@+1), as may perhaps appear below. – or specifically at this HNQ travesty we witnessed and had to suffer again.

Comment: I was making a joke guys, please stop telling me that Hitler wasn't a nice guy.

Answer (score 6):

I remember two jokes from in the book of William Shirer, in The Rise and Fall of the Third Reich.

One is regarding to the height to be accepted in the elite unit SS Leibstandarte Adolf Hitler.

> Hitler: What's the height to enter to the Leibstandarte SS?
>   Answer: 1.8 m
>   Hitler: It seems I'll have to apply to the infantry again.

And another, while being invaded by mosquitoes in the Wolfsschanze (Wolf's Lair, Hitler headquarters).

> Hitler: These mosquitoes are a job for the Luftwaffe.

I'm quoting from my memory. That's a book I borrowed 20 years ago from my local library. Spanish translation.

Comment: "Zatz not funny!" Sorry, I could not resist.

Comment: Looking into that book I fail to find the 'quotes', please recheck and back it up with  a little more precision. On this, I absolutely *require* scrutiny.

Comment: The latter is actually pretty funny considering the RAF had an aircraft called the Mosquito.

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer here: https://www.quora.com/What-type-of-jokes-would-Hitler-tell?share=1

> Göring, who was known to be very vain, fond of uniforms and high-sounding titles.
>
> One day, Mrs Göring walks into their bedroom and sees Göring standing by the bed with all his underwear laid out on it, and waiving his marshall staff over the bed.
> -But Hermann, what are you doing? she says.
> Göring answers: -I am promoting my underwear to overwear.

And this one:

> One joke Hitler told after negotiating for Franco to have Spain come into the war on the German side was that he would rather get worked over by his dentist than negotiate with him again. Franco was successful in staying out of the war.

OK I guess not very funny.

Comment: Quora can be a very unreliable source, unless the people posting there also cite their sources ...

Comment: Yes I agree. I will not accept my answer if there are better sources.

Comment: @sempaiscuba The first one is also mentioned by the Telegraph https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/worldnews/europe/germany/2185507/Adolf-Hitler-told-bad-jokes-about-Nazi-friends.html

Comment: @knallfrosch Yep, and they cite their source.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Do they? I looked into the German version & the transl. of that "according to the book". Must have missed it then. Can you point me to the page in that 'source' or how this 'joke' goes in the supposed German original?

Comment: @LаngLаngС  The source cited by the Telegraph is Hitler's Last Witness by Rochus Misch (although they managed to get the title wrong in their citation).  Whether that 'joke' actually appears in the book cited, or is just padding added by the reviewer, Richard Alleyne, is another matter (I haven't read the book, but I have read other book reviews by journalists in The Telegraph, so I won't be surprised if you say the 'joke' isn't there).

Comment: @sempaiscuba It does seem to be just padding added by the reviewer, but the follow up joke on medals does appear in *The Hitler Book*. I don't think Richard Alleyne got the title wrong; rather, it is a direct translation of the original in German (the English version hadn't been published at the time the article was written).

Comment: @LarsBosteen Fair enough.  I'm always just a little cautious about the standards of journalism at The Telegraph.  After all, that's where [Boris Johnson went to work](https://inews.co.uk/news/uk/times-boris-johnson-flat-lied-277588) after being sacked by The Times for lying! ;-)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Indeed, you are right to be cautious. Boris Johnson was the source of a bad citation concerning Lord Boothby and [Hitler saluting himself](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/54990/was-hitler-exclaiming-heil-hitler-himself-when-saluting?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

If we read diaries from Goebbels then every Nazi was a very joyous person, constantly joking. If he liked a person, he described him as witty. ("Him", as women seemed to lack in that department?). And the Führer was the most jocular of all, a jack of all trades.

Similarly, the memoirs of for example Traudl Junge or Albert Speer paint the picture that actually the Führer was [much funnier than Chaplin.](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2006/05/22/nazis-say-the-darnedest-things)

Seldom we see the actual jokes repeated verbatim. Often just the general topic.

But what do we learn from that.

That *we* are disgusting people.

StackExchange readers eager to read some nazi jokes told by the Führer himself? I will not retell those here.

That man was a human being, but [his private life is occulted to us](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/52941). Especially those memoirs from after the war are in general highly unreliable. Sources like 'Table Talk' and 'Speer' cannot be used uncritically for such purposes. Neither seemingly better ones like ["The Hitler Book"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitler_Book).

Just read Speer's memoirs, looking for jokes and read this assumed idiots as future readers:

> Along with his expressions of approval he made jokes about the "dusty bureaucrats."
>
> He mingled with the soldiers at the campfires, was surrounded by them, tossed jokes back and forth with them.

As just a few examples. And then a few pages later:

> Hitler had no humor. He left joking to others, although he could laugh loudly, abandonedly, sometimes literally writhing with laughter. Often he would wipe tears from his eyes during such spasms. He liked laughing, but it was always laughter at the expense of others.

There is no discrepancy here, no contradiction. Move on, nothing to see here.

As is, the question

> **Q** Did Hitler ever tell a joke?

is answered easily: "of course."

We usually get presented more an impression of a famous line alluding to his grab for power and the methods used:

> You will still remember the Reichstag session in which I declared: "If Judaism imagines that it can bring about an international world war to exterminate the European races, the result will not be the extermination of the European races, but the extermination of Judaism in Europe. [Applause] They have always laughed at me as a prophet. Of those who laughed back then, countless do not laugh today any longer [Laughter]. Those who laugh now may not laugh in the near future. [Applause]
> <sub>( — various variants. First version best known from July 1933, the extermination variant most well known above quoted from [November 8, 1942.](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Adolf_Hitler%27s_Stalingrad_Speech)) ([Original audio with eery laughter to *a few* of his jokes](https://archive.org/details/AdolfHitlerSpeechNovember81942).)</sub>

But of course humour was used to great effect by that man. Just see how funny the Germans above found the line about the just started full-on Holocaust and the plain allusion on internal opposition and Jews killed and no longer laughing or soon murdered. Entertainment at its best.

One of the best jokes he ever made, probably, judging by the enormous and raucous laughter he provoked in his listeners is telling the Reichstag practically his invasion plans, albeit in a list taken literally from President Roosevelt.

Reichstag speech 28. April 1939, Hitler, masterful teacher of geography, Göring jumping with joy like a hot grenade on the edge of his seat:

> [image]
> <sub>— Adolf Hitler / Rede / Berlin / Deutschland / 28.04.1939, [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtDxjVCu56E), [English translation transcript](http://comicism.tripod.com/390428.html)</sub>

<sub>— Albert Speer: "Inside the Third Reich. The memoirs of Albert Speer", translated from the German by Richard & Clara Winston, Macmillan, 1970.</sub>

<sub>— Ralf Georg Reuth (Ed): "Joseph Goebbels Tagebücher", Piper: München, Zürich <sup>3</sup>2003.</sub>

<sub>— Traudl Junge: "Bis zur letzten Stunde Hitlers Sekretärin erzählt ihr Leben", 2002.</sub>

<sub>— Heinz Linge: "With Hitler to the End: The Memoirs of Adolf Hitler's Valet", Grub Street, 2009.</sub>

<sub>— Henrik Eberle, Giles MacDonogh & Matthias Uhl (Eds): "The Hitler Book: The Secret Dossier Prepared for Stalin from the Interrogations of Otto Guensche and Heinze Linge, Hitler’s Closest Personal Aides", PublicAffairs, 2006.</sub>

Instead of giving in to a pathological fixation on the Führer and some of these repugnant fantasies, the following book is worthy of recommendation in this context:

— [Klaus Theweleit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klaus_Theweleit): "Das Lachen der Täter, Breivik U.A. Psychogramm der Tötungslust" (The laughter/smile of the perpetrators. Psychogram of the lust to kill), Residenzverlag: Wien, Salzburg, 2015.

---

In case *anyone* believes that "Göring promoting his underpants" was a joke Hitler told: That Telegraph article wants to imply that this was a newly revealed joke to be found in Misch's book. It is *not* in there. And neither is there anything about Hitler giving paper medals to Göring for use on his pyjamas. And, you guessed it by now, 'Heini near any fire' is also not in Misch's book.
The Telegraph doesn't cite any source. It is itself *the* source cited for autheticity [even on RationWiki!](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Hermann_G%C3%B6ring). As appalling as that is: [an earlier source published in 2000](https://books.google.com/books?id=bZQiAQAAIAAJ&q=g%C3%B6ring%20promoting%20underpants&dq=g%C3%B6ring%20promoting%20underpants) clearly depicts this as an underground joke. No connection to Misch whatsoever. [Just to Emmy and Hermann as the butt of the joke.](https://prabook.com/web/emmy.goring/1344842) Whether Hitler even knew these three jokes or went on to retell them? Pure speculation by a morbidly obsessed crowd. Nauseating.

And even if one were to take Misch somehow seriously and assume reliability:

> I cannot state for a fact that Hitler had a sense of humour. I never heard him laugh out loud.
>
> […] Hitler. ‘The boss’ himself had a small fund of jokes, which he liked to bring out from time to time. <sub>(What follows is a sexist prank involving his dog…)</sub>

Yeah. Totally reliable, again.
<sub>— Rochus Misch: "Der Letzte Zeuge. »Ich war Hitlers Telefonist, Kurier und Leibwächter«", Pendo: Zürich, München, 2008.</sub>
<sub>— Rochus Misch: "Hitler’s Last Witness. The Memoirs of Hitler’s Bodyguard", Frontline Books, London, 2014.</sub>

> [Hitler loved jokes. […] Hitler himself was a good joke teller; he could imitate the tone of voice, facial expressions and dialect of others in a variety of ways.](https://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/print/d-46163085.html)

Adapted from where?

> Hitler loved jokes. Since he had a phenomenal memory, he was able to tell a great many of them, revealing a striking ability to imitate expressions, voices, and dialects. But he never told off-color stories, let alone dirty jokes.
>
> At the same time, however, Schramm's interpretation of Hitler is disturbing. It is disturbing to see in that consummately evil man so many commonly and legitimately admired virtues so clearly mirrored. They are not even parodied; they are genuine. Hitler was, beyond any doubt, a man of uncommon self-discipline who led what can be fairly described as a relatively austere personal life. It is not congenial to think of him in this way. It is not congenial to see him portrayed as a charming gentleman with a quick wit and a wholesome sense of humor.
> <sub>— Percy Ernst Schramm: "Hitler: the man and the military leader", Quadrangle Books: Chicago, 1971.</sub>

Portions of that book are translated into English and recycled from Schramm's edition of 'Table Talk', 1961. This quote instead is from the introduction of the English book, written by editor and translator Donald S. Detwiler.<sup>(p10)</sup>

Ah well, why not?

Why? This unreliable source that is 'Table Talk' alone has numerous examples of this 'wholesome' humour, so funny that some German editions explain with editorial remarks that they are: funny! And yes, that was an order.

A German source for this 'Göring underpants' joke — a secretive underground joke, *not* told by Hilter — would not work well with 'underpants' on a language level. One version circulating among the people, and using *Unterhemden/*–undershirts, is to be found in:
— Hans-Joachim Gamm: "Der Flüsterwitz im Dritten Reich", Paul List Verlag: München, **1963.**

---

Concerning the 'talking to Franco is worse than going to a dentist':

This is also most often hearsay. Even published historians using second-, third-hand or worse 'quoting'.
In German the quote is often used with *"Zähne ziehen"*, while it was quite popular in the 70s to use *"reißen"*. Then we see books 'quoting' this and leaving it either unreferenced, or pointing to works that do not contain this 'quote'.

How did it come to this telephone game for a seemingly straight forward German quote even in the German language?

The main German sources for this 'quote' are given as two diaries: Paul Schmidt (Hitler's translator), Ulrich von Hassell (diplomat). Both Germans, both writing after the war, both referencing a meeting in October 1940 in Hendaye. But they do *not* tell us much teethy things. Both are referenced in papers *together,* as corroborating references.<sup>*</sup> For the general meeting and the frustrations voiced by Ribbentrop and Hitler. In English works the most often referenced source are 'Diplomatic Paper's' of Count Ciano of Italy, quoted from the 1948 English translation (p402 in that one).

This is interesting as Ciano – in *very stark contrast* to what is often counted here and elsewhere as 'yoohoo, a Hitler quote' – did not have the chance to rewrite his past since he died before the war was over. In the Italian original of his we read:

> Ma a questa conclusione si è giunti molto faticosamente dopo un colloquio durato nove ore, colloquio che, "piuttosto che riaverlo il Führer preferirebbe farsi togliere tre o quattro denti".
> <sub>— Galeazzo Ciano: ["L'Europa Verso La Catastrofe"](https://books.google.com/books?id=R5hUAAAAYAAJ) (p604); translated into English as ["Ciano’s Diplomatic Papers", by Stuart Hood, Malcolm Muggeridge (Ed), Odhams Press: London, 1948.](https://www.worldcat.org/title/cianos-diplomatic-papers-being-a-record-of-nearly-200-conversations-held-during-the-years-1936-42-with-hitler-mussolini-franco-goering-ribbentrop-chamberlain-eden-sumner-welles-schuschnigg-lord-perth-francois-poncet-and-many-other-world-diplomatic-and-political-figures-together-with-important-memoranda-letters-telegrams-etc/oclc/1085348)</sub>

Which explains nicely why translations, especially German ones, often differ in the exact wording of what looks to be a direct German quote. Looks to me as if too many German works also quote from the English version?

The remaining problem with that 'quote'?

In parallel to his official minutes from diplomatic talks he also kept a detailed private [diary](https://books.google.com/books?id=EH7FvwEACAAJ). This work does *not* mention Hitler's teeth or preferences for or against any dental procedures.

Some deliver decent and transparent work, some go into details and others work with what's available to them. But some are just too lazy and jump to unacceptable conclusions and perpetrate myths for the cheapest entertainment.

---

<sub>* Disclaimer: I did not have the opportunity to consult von Hassell's expanded diaries, only the old and therefore obviously incomplete ones. *If* the late 80s version has that anecdote, 'Franco-or-teeth-pulling' may have indeed *two* sources for attestation. Currently, I doubt that a bit.</sub>

Comment: "That we are disgusting people. StackExchange readers eager to read some nazi jokes told by the Führer himself?"  
For all your value judgements, hardly anyone cares about Nazi jokes. Most people are just curious whether he was descended from hell and ate babies for breakfast, or whether he was a human. Because it feels doubtful and counter-intuitive somehow that he was human.

Comment: It is actually quite better for us all if we do believe that he is human. If we do, then we find ourselves asking, "How did someone who was once like us become this monster?" and from our consideration of that question learn to not become monsters. If we reject the notion, then we risk becoming monsters, albeit of a different kind, and in denial that this has happened.

Comment: @EvilSnack And, what did I write above? He *was* one, no need to *believe* outlandish things. Or taking part in rumor mongering about nazi jokes, told by nazis, banalising evil even further. The HotNetworkCuntry-effect is a disgrace all around. Here: Sensationalist clickbait, low quality question, posted by a previously massively upvoted on PolSE right winger & Holocaust-relativist. Uncritical source usage in answers, if sourced at all, cargo-cult-history, but still UV'd. Now, everyday fascists don't like what they see in any mirrors. Some are disappointed: lack of humor in this post? Ha!

Comment: @EvilSnack Sociopath Next Door https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmpUDU4y0Cg

Comment: @LаngLаngС You are doing yourself a great disservice with your tone. I do not know the OP or their background, but I found their question quite reasonable. I also found your answer to be a really great source of information, but reading it was quite atrocious due to your very aggressive tone and judgmental attitude. Please consider to edit it to focus on the facts. It would greatly improve the quality of your answer.

Comment: After all these atrocities found in treating the this subject, which I prove with sources in this answer, people still upvote that stuff and think the *tone* in this A is the problem? This is an unbelievably, primitive farce.

Comment: *This is an unbelievably, primitive farce* Farce is a form of humor.  ;-)   If I may quote Sergeant Helka (Stripes, the movie) I think that Polygnome is suggesting  a bit of "Lighten up, Francis" (And you sure did dig up a lot of info, nicely done)